# Set parent link active if child or grandchild link is active using CSS

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, css-selectors

I have a HTML/CSS menu with this CSS for the active links:

```
.navigation ul li a:hover, .navigation .active-nav {
    background-color: #F36F25; /*#373737;*/
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #f7f7f7 !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ff8833;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ff8833;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kyvbzssd/

How can I set the top parent link as active if any of its child or its child's child links have an active class?

Comment: there is no parent selector - how is your menu generated?

Comment: sorry im not sure what you mean?

Comment: how is your HTML for your menu created?

Comment: its created through PHP queries, i have just seen i missed out a `</li>` in one of the PHP loops so re formatted it here: http://jsfiddle.net/kyvbzssd/1/

Comment: Since it is not possible with CSS, is it possible to add the `active-nav` class via php? This is not something you should do using Javascript if it can be avoided.

Answer (score 11):

Add the style to your li element as well : http://jsfiddle.net/kyvbzssd/3/

```
.navigation ul li{
    padding: 80px 9px 10px;
}
.navigation ul li a,.navigation ul li{
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #4d4d4d;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .2s linear, padding-top .2s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color .2s linear, padding-top .2s linear;
    -o-transition: background-color .2s linear, padding-top .2s linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color .2s linear, padding-top .2s linear;
    transition: background-color .2s linear, padding-top .2s linear;
}
.navigation ul li a:hover,.navigation ul li:hover,.navigation .active-nav {
    background-color: #F36F25; /*#373737;*/
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #f7f7f7!important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ff8833;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ff8833;
}
```

Comment: how about if i had this - http://jsfiddle.net/kyvbzssd/13/ - how can i make each parent item have an active class if the child items have it?

Comment: Very good work on this answer. And it proofes that other guy wrong "It's not possible only by css."... :) +

Answer (score 6):

Here is a Pure CSS Solution by using `:hover` state and reusing it again.

- Here you apply the style you desire for you `:hover` state:

```css
li:hover a {
  color: orange;
  font-weight: 700
}
```

- Now you prevent the `li` children being hovered over

```css
li:hover li a {
  color: none;
  font-weight: 400
}
```

And finally, you re-do the `:hover` state for `li` children

```css
li:hover li:hover a {
  color: orange;
  font-weight: 700
}
```

---

Here is a Snippet: (this is a working demo only, I just used your HTML code)

```css
li:hover a {
  color: orange;
  font-weight: 700
}
li:hover li a {
  color: none;
  font-weight: 400
}
li:hover li:hover a {
  color: orange;
  font-weight: 700
}
```

```html
<nav id="main-navigation" class="navigation cf">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Homepage</a>
    </li>
    <li class="">
      <a href="#">About Us</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">The Company</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Careers</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Meet The Team</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Broadband</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Telecoms</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="active-nav">Hosted IP PBX</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Telephone Numbers</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Traditional Lines</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Telephone Systems</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">I.T. Support</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Offsite Backup</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Web Hosting</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Hosted Exchange</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Networking</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Security</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">CCTV Systems</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Access Control</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Login</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#">Online Shop</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Shopping Cart</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Support</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

---

**UPDATE** as discussed with OP (in chatroom), here is a snippet with OP's Code (worked by me):

### Snippet

```css
/*OP' code simplified */

/*1st menu*/

.navigation ul {
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1200;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.navigation ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.navigation ul li a {
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #4d4d4d;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
  transition: background-color .2s linear, padding-top .2s linear;
  padding: 80px 9px 10px;
}
.navigation ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #F36F25;
  /*#373737;*/
  text-shadow: none;
  color: #f7f7f7!important;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ff8833;
}
.navigation ul li a span {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 9px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 14px;
  color: #9f9f9f;
}
/*2nd menu */

.navigation ul ul {
  margin-top: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: -999em;
  width: 180px;
  background: #fff;
  border-top: 3px solid #ff8833;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
.navigation ul ul li {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.navigation ul ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #F36F25;
  /*#373737;*/
  box-shadow: none;
}
.navigation ul ul li a {
  color: #707070;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-left: 0;
  border: none;
  width: 150px;
  transition: none;
  padding: 8px 15px;
}
.navigation ul li:hover ul {
  left: 0;
  top: 2.5em;
  z-index: 99;
}
/*3rd menu */

.navigation ul li:hover li ul {
  top: -999em;
  margin-top: 0;
}
.navigation ul li li:hover ul {
  left: 180px;
  top: 0;
}
.navigation ul li li:hover li ul {
  top: -999em;
}
.navigation ul ul li a {
  position: relative;
}
.navigation ul ul li a i {
  position: absolute;
  right: 15px;
  line-height: 23px;
  font-size: 14px;
}
/* my code */

.navigation ul li:hover a {
  background: #F36F25;
  font-weight: 700
}
.navigation li:hover li a {
  background: none;
  font-weight: 400
}
.navigation ul li:hover li:hover a {
  background: #F36F25;
  font-weight: 700
}
/*2nd sub-level menu only */
.navigation ul li:hover li:hover > ul li a {
  background: none;
  font-weight: 400
}
.navigation ul li:hover li:hover > ul li:hover a {
  background: #F36F25;
  font-weight: 700
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<nav id="main-navigation" class="navigation cf">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Homepage</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">About Us</a>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">The Company</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Careers</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Meet The Team</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Services</a>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Broadband</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Telecoms</a>

          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Hosted IP PBX</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Telephone Numbers</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Traditional Lines</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Telephone Systems</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">I.T. Support</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Offsite Backup</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Web Hosting</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Hosted Exchange</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Networking</a>

        </li>
        <li> <a href="#">Security</a>

          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">CCTV Systems</a>

            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Access Control</a>

            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Login</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#">Online Shop</a>

      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Shopping Cart</a>

        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Support</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a>

    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

---

Below is the

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sdytwrgw/)

Comment: im sorry to be a pain but im not that great with CSS - how can i implement this on my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/kyvbzssd/ ?

Comment: Hi, your menu is quiet confusing , that's why I tried to simplify in my demo, I even can't reach to child-menu items when hovering the parent menu items. Anyway here is a Fiddle with my code "inside" yours [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ptceazku/)

Comment: this works okay here - http://jsfiddle.net/ptceazku/1/, but if the active link is a child's child (http://jsfiddle.net/ptceazku/2/) its not showing active

Comment: can u be more specific? which link?

Comment: they BOTH work the same way for me, ScreenShot please!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ptceazku/1/ has an active link (About Us) which works and http://jsfiddle.net/ptceazku/2/ has an active link (The Company) which does NOT show

Comment: just change `.active-nav`from `a` to `li`, see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/71gg6zqm/)

Comment: but the About Us link is not active? i want all parent items to have active class

Comment: Come [here](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83919/discussion-between-dippas-and-charlie) please!

Comment: check my latest comment on that answer

Comment: what would be the JS needed to achieve the active links for the active item and all its parents

Comment: @charlie You really don't need Javascript at all. See my answer @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099465/set-active-links-in-html-menu-using-css/31573354#31573354 for a fully optimised, CSS only solution.

Comment: @charlie as we discussed here is the full snippet with your code. (as you seen it before in chatroom). Answer was updated. Sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 6):

You can use selector `.navigation li:hover > a` to style both the menu item currently active **AND** all of its ancestor menu items (parent, grandparent, ...).

I added this to your demo, removed unused styles, optimised your selectors and made several other improvements.

You can find the result in the JSFiddle and code snippet below.

### The Fiddle :

**http://jsfiddle.net/py72ms93/1/**

### The code :

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

main, footer {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px;
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}

p, h1 {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 80%;
}

main {
    border: 0 solid #d9d9d9;
    border-width: 3px 0;
    background: #eee;
}

header, footer {
    background: #fff;
    text-align: right;
}

.navigation {
    background: #fff;
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
}

.navigation ul {
    background: #fff;
    border: 0 solid #ff8833;
    margin: 0 15px 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    float: right;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1200;
}

.navigation li ul {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -999em;
    z-index: 99;
    width: 210px;
    border-width: 3px 0 0 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.navigation li li ul {
    border-width: 0;
    left: 100%;
}

.navigation li:hover > ul {
    top: 6.75em;
}

.navigation li li:hover > ul {
    top: 0;
}

.navigation li {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}

.navigation li li {
    width: 100%;
}

.navigation li a {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: #4d4d4d;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
    -webkit-transition: background-color .2s linear, padding-top .2s linear;
    -moz-transition: background-color .2s linear, padding-top .2s linear;
    -o-transition: background-color .2s linear, padding-top .2s linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color .2s linear, padding-top .2s linear;
    transition: background-color .2s linear, padding-top .2s linear;
    padding: 80px 9px 10px;
}


.navigation li:hover > a,.navigation .active-nav {
    background-color: #F36F25;
    color: #f7f7f7;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ff8833;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 0 #ff8833;
}

.navigation li li a {
    color: #707070;
    font-size: 11px;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 8px 30px;
    border: none;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    -ms-transition: none;
    transition: none;
}

.navigation li li:hover > a {
    box-shadow: none;
}

.navigation li li > a:not(:last-child):after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    right: 1em;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    z-index: 99;
    top: .7em;
    border: .6em solid transparent;
    border-right-width: 0;
    border-left-color: #707070;
}

.navigation li li:hover > a:not(:last-child):after {
    border-left-color: #f7f7f7;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <nav id="main-navigation" class="navigation cf">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/new/homepage" class="active-nav">Homepage</a></li>
            <li><a href="/new/about">About Us</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/new/the-company">The Company</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/new/testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/new/careers">Careers</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/new/the-company#meet-the-team">Meet The Team</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/new/services">Services</a><ul>
                    <li><a href="/new/broadband">Broadband</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/new/telecoms">Telecoms</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/new/hosted-ip-pbx">Hosted IP PBX</a>
                            <li><a href="/new/voip-telephone-numbers">Telephone Numbers</a>
                            <li><a href="/new/traditional-lines">Traditional Lines</a>
                            <li><a href="/new/telephone-systems">Telephone Systems</a>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="/new/it-support">I.T. Support</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/new/offsite-backup">Offsite Backup</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/new/web-hosting">Web Hosting</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/new/hosted-exchange">Hosted Exchange</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/new/networking">Networking</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/new/security">Security</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="/new/cctv-systems">CCTV Systems</a>
                            <li><a href="/new/access-control">Access Control</a>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="/new/login">Login</a></li>
            <li><a href="/new/online-shop">Online Shop</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="/new/online-shop/cart">Shopping Cart</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li><li><a href="/new/support">Support</a></li>
            <li><a href="/new/contact">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<main class="cf">
    <h1>Page title</h1>
    <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. Donec pede justo, fringilla vel, aliquet nec, vulputate eget, arcu. In enim justo, rhoncus ut, imperdiet a, venenatis vitae, justo. Nullam dictum felis eu pede mollis pretium. Integer tincidunt. Cras dapibus. Vivamus elementum semper nisi. Aenean vulputate eleifend tellus. Aenean leo ligula, porttitor eu, consequat vitae, eleifend ac, enim. Aliquam lorem ante, dapibus in, viverra quis, feugiat a, tellus. Phasellus viverra nulla ut metus varius laoreet. Quisque rutrum. Aenean imperdiet. Etiam ultricies nisi vel augue. Curabitur ullamcorper ultricies nisi. Nam eget dui. Etiam rhoncus. Maecenas tempus, tellus eget condimentum rhoncus, sem quam semper libero, sit amet adipiscing sem neque sed ipsum. Nam quam nunc, blandit vel, luctus pulvinar, hendrerit id, lorem. Maecenas nec odio et ante tincidunt tempus. Donec vitae sapien ut libero venenatis faucibus. Nullam quis ante. Etiam sit amet orci eget eros faucibus tincidunt. Duis leo. Sed fringilla mauris sit amet nibh. Donec sodales sagittis magna. Sed consequat, leo eget bibendum sodales, augue velit cursus nunc,
    </p>
</main>
<footer>
    Page footer
</footer>
```

Comment: ok great - although check here: http://jsfiddle.net/py72ms93/2/ - how can i make the parent link also show active when its children are active?

Comment: @charlie if what you say is setting the active class by code and have the parent automatically have it as well, it can't be done with css only.

Comment: @charlie : When go over a link, the link should have an orange background + white text. So should its parent & grandparent menu items. Isn't that the effect you want? And if not, what do you mean when you say you want parent links to "show active"?

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible only by css. You should use some javascript codes.

```
$('.child').on('click', function(){
   $(this).closest('.parent').toggleClass('active');
});
```

Comment: i dont have these classes here: jsfiddle.net/kyvbzssd/1

Comment: That was just a sample. I think you want to prevent hiding menu, when you are hovering on its children. Is that right?

Comment: how should i set these classes as i have `parent > child > child` or `parent > parent > child`

Comment: @charlie You really don't need Javascript at all. See my answer @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099465/set-active-links-in-html-menu-using-css/31573354#31573354 for a fully optimised, CSS only solution.

Answer (score 1):

As of now(2015) there is no way to do this using CSS only.
However, you can do this using Jquery.
`$("a.active").parents('li').css("property", "value");`